# Sort a list by self defined

Tags: java, sorting

Example:
Original list
[click here to check original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vJQA.png)

staff_id     staff_name     position_id        date
  1           Ada             5              201711 
  2           Anna            5              201711
  3           Jack            6              201711
  1           Ada             6              201712
  2           Anna            6              201712
  1           Ada             7              201801

After sorted:[click here to check sorted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE59J.png)

staff_id     staff_name     position_id        date
 3           Jack            6              201711
 2           Anna            6              201712 
 2           Anna            5              201711 
 1           Ada             7              201801
 1           Ada             6              201712 
 1           Ada             5              201711 
These data are about the promotion/demotion records of staffs.For staff  "Jack",his position is not changed ,while Ada is promoted 3 times.
The sort regulation is:  if the staff_id is unique(position not changed), we do not care about its order.What we need to sort is staff who has several records(staff_id is not unique).The record whose date is largest is stable, based on this record, other records of the same staff should be sorted by date descendingly.For example, the largest date in promotion information of Ada is 201801, so we do not change the largest date 's order(relative to other staffs).Then the second largest date is 201712, we put it next to the  "201801".

```
List<Object[]> resultListOrder=...

 for(Object[] rowOrder:resultListOrder)
   {
      for(Object[] row:resultListOrder)
      {
          if((int)rowOrder[0] ==(int) row[0]&&(int)rowOrder[4]>(int)row[4])
            {
               Object[] tempRow = row;
               resultListOrder.remove(resultListOrder.indexOf(row));
               resultListOrder.add(resultListOrder.indexOf(rowOrder)+1,tempRow);

            }
      }
  }
```

This code is correct in logic,but it throws ConcurrentModificationException.And It seems Iterator does not work here. 
Then I use

```
  resultListOrder.sort((m1, m2) -> {
        if((int)m1[0] ==(int) m2[0]){

             return (int)m1[4]>(int)m2[4] ? -1 : 1;
        }
        else return 0;

    });
```

But it dose not work ,so how to sort the list?

Comment: Try using a debugger to check your sort logic

Comment: _" if the staff_id is unique(position not changed), we do not care about its order"_  You may not "care", but you either have to eliminate it or put it someplace, and you need to specify where it goes.

Comment: Actually, the order of every staff is stable.The order of every staff depends on the order of largest date  . In original data, the largest date of Jack is 201711 and this record is put on the first row of all the records, so Jack 's order is 1 among 3 staffs.Then the largest date of Anna is 201712, and the order of this record is between Jack and Ada, thus Anna's order is 2. Ada's order is 3.As a result, the order of every staff in sorted data is the same, Jack is 1 , Anna is 2 and Ada is 3. what we need to do is resorting the order of  staff who has multiple records

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your first attempt with simple for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < resultListOrder.size(); i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < resultListOrder.size(); j++) {
      if((int)resultListOrder.get(i)[0] ==(int) resultListOrder.get(j)[0]&&(int)resultListOrder.get(i)[4]>(int)resultListOrder.get(j)[4]) {
           Object[] tempRow = resultListOrder.get(j);
           resultListOrder.remove(j);
           resultListOrder.add(i+1,tempRow);
        }
   }
}
```

However, I have strong doubts if your algoritm is correct.

Comment: That was just a doubt, it may be wrong. I just answered to you question and showed a way to rewrite you sorting algorithm. This way you should not get a ConcurrentModificationException. Did you try it?